# Skip #define in 3rd-party library

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I use `Adafruit BME280 Library` library for my Arduino project.
It has a line:

```
#define BME280_ADDRESS (0x77)
```

Real address is `0x76`, but `0x77` is defined in internals of the library:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BME280_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_BME280.h#L37

How can I set `0x76` value without forking library or changing its code?

P.S. I use `lib_deps` from `PlatformIO` for managing my dependencies.

**Update:** This code (afer `#include` blocks) does not work:

```
#undef BME280_ADDRESS
#define BME280_ADDRESS (0x76)
```

Comment: Where do you want to change it e.g. in your own code?

Comment: Read much more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

Comment: What is the meaning of "the real address"? Why is it different from the library?

Comment: @Azeem in any place.

Comment: @Andreas yes, it's different, another variation of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pre-processor directives to do this as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55217402/7670262).

Another option is simply compile this with your own code. From the [repo](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BME280_Library), this library is just two files i.e. `Adafruit_BME280.h` / `Adafruit_BME280.cpp`. You can simply change the macro and use it as-is. It'll be statically linked to your application unless you compile it as a dynamic lib yourself.

But, you don't have to do anything like that because there are different overloads of `Adafruit_BME280::begin()` function that you can use to provide your own custom `addr` value.

`Adafruit_BME280.h` file (Lines # [202-203](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BME280_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_BME280.h#L202-L203)):

```
    bool begin(uint8_t addr);
    bool begin(uint8_t addr, TwoWire *theWire);
```

Also, check the [examples](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BME280_Library/tree/master/examples) for further understanding.

Comment: `Adafruit_BME280::begin(uint8_t addr, TwoWire *theWire)` is a solution, thank you. Also I posted another solution with dynamic build flags.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you can use `#undef BME280_ADDRESS` to cancel the macro.

`#undef` only affect the code which is below the `#undef`.So if you are using it in different files, you should add that to every file you used.

If the library has been already compiled, the only way to change the macro is to recompile it.

Comment: Followed by a `#define BME280_ADDRESS 0x76`

Comment: The #define is a pre-compile code, it will be replaced after pre-compile. If you mean using it in your code, it will work. But if you mean in already compiled library, it will not work.

Comment: From the question it looks like the library is already compiled. Otherwise, just updating the macro and recompiling the library would have worked. @DmitryR Please confirm.

Comment: @mayurk The code is not compiled yet, it's a pair of cpp/h files. But it's a 3rd party lib that is downloaded automatically. I've added `update 1` section in the post

Comment: @DmitryR If library is not compiled yet and you have the source code, then I don't understand why can't you just update the original macro?

Answer (score 1):

The question was downwoted because it seems to be similar to other question, but it's not: I can't `undef` variable from  another 3rd party object.

The solution is to modify downloaded library by regexp on build step using dynamic build flags: `!python extra_script.py`

It's a dirty solution, but it's authomated and does not require any manual actions. Only `git clone` and push build button in IDE.